# How to access a UserControl from a WPF ribbon button

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a `TabControl` and the `TabItems` are dynamically created. A `UserControl` containing a `DataGrid` is placed on the `TabItems`. When a user clicks a ribbon button (save, delete, etc.) the following code runs:

```
//get the class name from the selected tab

var controlName = selectedTab.Content.ToString();

// Get a type from the string
Type type = Type.GetType(controlName);

// Create an instance of that type
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Retrieve the method you are looking for
MethodInfo methodinfo = type.GetMethod(theMethod);

// Invoke the method on the instance 
methodinfo.Invoke(obj, null);
```

The ribbon is paced on the main window of the application. My problem is that when a user enters data in a `DataGrid` and clicks the save button the last row is not saved by the `context.SaveChanges()` method. I would like call `myDataGrid.CommitEdit()` before calling `context.SaveChanges()`. The problem is that the above code only works through a static method in the `UserControl`. The static method does not allow me access to the `DataGrid`. What can I do to cause `context.SaveChanges()` to save the last row on the `DataGrid`. Is there a way that I can access the `DataGrid` to call the `CommitEdit` method?

Comment: On your grid lostfocus event you can do myDataGrid.CommitEdit().

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for the suggestion. It did not work. Placing myDataGrid.CommitEdith() in the lostfocus event made it impossible for the users to enter data in the Grid. I do not know if that has anything to do with entity framework.